# Как исправить ошибку ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKit'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

У меня версия Python 3.6.5

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow
```

Comment: Porting from Qt WebKit to Qt WebEngine  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка, правильно будет обращаться к `WebEngine`:

```
...
from PyQt5.QtWebEngine import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
...
```

---

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


app = QApplication([])

view = QWebEngineView()
view.show()

url = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/864975/201445'
view.load(QUrl(url))

app.exec()
```

---

**PS.**
`WebKit` поддерживался только для `Qt4` в модулях `pyqt4` и `pyside`.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, у вас довольно свежая версия Qt. А там уже QWebKit заменен на [QWebEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtwebengine-modules.html).

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QWebEngine

Comment: @Slavik0981 [вот тут](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/QtWebEngineWidgets.html#PyQt5-QtWebEngineWidgets) можно увидеть, что общий модуль называется немного не так. Пользуйтесь документацией;)